# NullPointerException on text.settext(..)

Tags: java, android

```
private TextView text;

if(available == true){
        View view = (View)findViewById(R.id.emptyprogram);
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        filldata();
    } else {
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emptyprogram);
        text.setText("Tiada Rancangan Yang Sedang Atau Akan Disiarkan!!!");
    }
}
```

When I execute, it gave me `NullPointerException` error on the line `text.settext("...");`

What is the problem? I run on another side, it got no problem.

Comment: First tell me why you used `if(available == true)` and not `if(available)` ? Braces are also not proper. There is one extra bracket. ***i run on another side, it got no problem.*** which other side?

Comment: the only way you can get a null pointer on that line is if `findViewById` is returning null.

Comment: "There is no current or future design broadcast!!!" ?

Comment: @harry: the available no problem only the problem is why text is null

Comment: I asume that @newonadroid was running on **the dark side**, the iOS one? It's fun that it doesn't even make sense to downvote it. Anyway, **Tidak ada masa depan dengan NullPointerException sederhana.**.

Answer (score 4):

This method call must be returning `null`

```
findViewById(R.id.emptyprogram);
```

When you try to invoke the `setText` method in the next line, you get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: why it will be null?
my other textview call r.id.emptycandidate also no returning null

Comment: @newonandroid - I can't possibly answer that without seeing the source code of the method. Have you checked that the **value** of the parameter is the same both times it's called?

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `setContentView()` before calling `findViewById()`? You have to create your UI  and only then can use it..

Comment: Put the code of xml here and how you call setContentView() then, because this is the cause of problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're afraid textView is null, try this one to avoid exception:

```
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emptyprogram);
if(text != null)
    text.setText("Tiada Rancangan Yang Sedang Atau Akan Disiarkan!!!");
```

Comment: This is only appropriate if there is some resonable way of handling a null `text`. If `text` is never expected to be null here, then throwing a NPE is preferable to the code above, because the code above will merely mask the underlying problem